# Is there a total language that can express any halting algorithm, or a proof that such a language cannot exist?

Tags: computability, formal-languages, turing-machines

Conjecture: there is a language L with the following properties:

1. There is a halting algorithm that checks whether program P is in L.
2. There is a halting evaluation algorithm E(P, I) that runs any pair of program P in L and input I.
3. For any halting algorithm P' (represented as a state and an instruction table for a Turing machine) there is a program P in L such that for any input I, E(P, I) = P'(I). That is, there is a program that always produces the same output.

There is no need for a halting algorithm that would check whether algorithm P' has an equivalent program P in L. That would be undecidable.

Question: is there an example of L? Is there a formal proof that L is impossible? Is there a formal proof that this question is also undecidable?

Comment: Inspired by a LambdaTheUltimate thread: http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/3470

Comment: Why doesn't the set of (indices for) all programs satisfy these requirements? It seems to satisfy both (1) and (2) trivially (always say "yes" for (1), and take P=P' for (2)). Do you want to require additionally that L consists *only* of (indices for) halting algorithms (which I assume are just Turing machines halting on every input)?

Comment: Right, I'll explicitly add a third property: there is an interpreter for L that always halts

Comment: There is an algorithm generating only the programs that halt when ran with the empty input, there is no always halting algorithm checking if a given program is in that set, there is no algorithm generating only the programs that halt on all input. There is an algorithm generating only the programs for which there is a proof in ZFC that it halts on all input.

Comment: What you want can be more succinctly stated as "A computable set of Turing machines containing a decision machine for each computable set" - or perhaps something similar allowing for non-binary outputs (though it does not matter). As in the existing answer, this is impossible by a very similar argument to why the halting problem is - we can have a machine which evaluates other machine applied to representations of themselves - and then evaluate *it* on itself and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Below I'll conflate algorithms, Turing machines, and indices for such.*

The answer is **no** since we can diagonalize. By $(1)$ we can enumerate the elements of $L$ as $e_0,e_1,e_2,...$, but then we can diagonalize: let $M$ be the machine which, on input $i$, runs machine $e_i$ on input $i$ and outputs $1$ + the result.

(Note that dropping the requirement that $L$ consist only of halting algorithms - which is equivalent, given $(1)$, to your $(2)$ - makes the answer trivially **yes** since we can then take $L$ to be the set of all programs.)

---

Incidentally, although it's totally unrelated I can't help mentioning a deeply surprising *positive* result: there is a computable set of Turing machine such that every Turing machine appears up to equivalence *exactly once* on the list! Such sets are called Friedberg numberings; see [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397590901414) for a quick proof of their existence by Kummer, substantially simplifying the original proof by Friedberg. This is *almost* impossible; the saving grace is that we don't require (and indeed, can't have) a computable way to tell *where* a given Turing machine appears up to equivalence in the set.

In terms of programming languages, this means that we can whip up a language MWAHAHAH with the following seemingly-contradictory properties:

- Every algorithm is indeed implementable in MWAHAHAH.
- Programming as we understand it is impossible, since there is no general procedure for telling what program in MWAHAHAH performs a given algorithm.

As far as I know, nobody's actually produced such a language, but since the existence proof is totally explicit it would be a fun exercise for somebody who really loves terrible things.

Comment: Yep, I want L to only represent halting algorithms. I've mentioned it in the title, and it was implied by (3), but I inserted property (2) for clarity.

Comment: @Kinrany I've edited (and added an interesting aside just for fun).

Comment: Does L still have to be enumerable even if the algorithm in (1) only halts for valid L programs?

Comment: @Kinrany Yes - if you have an algorithm which is guaranteed to halt and accept every element of $L$, but not to accept (and possibly not to halt) on any other element, you can write an algorithm enumerating $L$ - the way you do this is to note that running the decision algorithm for $n$ steps on all inputs of length up to $n$ only takes finitely many steps - so your enumerator can just do that with $n=1$ then $n=2$ then $n=3$ and so on and outputting whenever the decision algorithm identifies something as belonging to $L$.

Comment: Does this still hold if the input language is also infinite? Or is this completely outside the standard discussion of Turing machines, since they assume finite alphabet?

Comment: @Kinrany Yes - we can make sense of computation with (say) $\mathbb{N}$ as an input language (e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter_machine)), and the results above still hold.